# Issues with multiline UILabel in UIStackView

Tags: swift, uikit, uistackview

I have following code that used to work fine when using a label with a single line, but breaks now that the label is set to multiline. Here's the relevant code:

```
  private let label: UILabel = {
        let label = CKLabel.multilineLabel()
        return label
    }()

    private lazy var iconView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = TintedImageView(tintColor: style.textColor)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()

    private let contentStackView = UIStackView(alignment: .center, spacing: Constants.imageTitleSpacing)

private func setupViews() {
        layer.addCornerRadius(KPL.BorderRadius.default)

        contentStackView.setArrangedSubviews([iconView, label])
        addSubview(contentStackView)
        contentStackView.edgesToSuperview(insets: Constants.contentInsets)
        iconView.height(Constants.iconHeight)
        iconView.widthToHeight()
    }
```

Here's what the view looks like before and after the multiline change. Note that everything works fine if the icon is set to hidden.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

Embedding the label in a UIView fixed the issue.